# Touchscreen Issue on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: drivers, touchscreen, 23.04

**UPDATE:** I perused dmesg some more and found the following that coincides every time I try to load the goodix_ts module.

```
[98756.097733] gpio gpiochip0: (INT3453:00): gpiochip_lock_as_irq: tried to flag a GPIO set as output for IRQ
[98756.097742] gpio gpiochip0: (INT3453:00): unable to lock HW IRQ 26 for IRQ
```

This looks like the GPIO pin the touchscreen is trying to use is set for output only.  I've seen some similar posts about modifying DSDT tables to correct these types of issues, but it's a little beyond my understanding currently.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**ORIGINAL POST:** I recently purchased a "no-brand" mini laptop off eBay that came with Windows 11 pre-installed.  The device has a built-in mouse and capacitive touchscreen that works fine under Windows.  The pre-installed version of windows was not activated and would not activate so I suspect it may have been counterfeit.  Rather than purchase a windows license I opted to install Ubuntu 23.04 to try and get the latest hardware support.  Everything worked well other than the left mouse click, sound, and the touchscreen.  I was able to get the left mouse click to work by switching from Wayland back to X-Org and using some xkbset commands in a startup application.  The sound I fixed by creating another startup application to issue some alsa commands to change some sound levels.  The touchscreen however is giving me issues and I can't figure out how to correct the problem.  It's being detected as a Goodix Touchscreen and it's completely unresponsive.

Here is some info I've collected on my machine that shows the errors in dmesg related to the touchscreen, as well as some other associated info.

```
root@Frenzy:~# ls /sys/bus/i2c/devices/
i2c-0  i2c-10  i2c-12  i2c-3  i2c-5  i2c-7  i2c-9            i2c-GDIX1002:00
i2c-1  i2c-11  i2c-2   i2c-4  i2c-6  i2c-8  i2c-ESSX8336:00  i2c-HTIX5288:00

root@Frenzy:~# lsmod | grep goodix
goodix_ts              40960  0

root@Frenzy:~# dmesg | grep GDIX
[    5.989730] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: supply AVDD28 not found, using dummy regulator
[    6.036549] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: supply VDDIO not found, using dummy regulator
[    6.039069] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: Unexpected ACPI resources: gpio_count 1, gpio_int_idx 0
[    6.241191] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: ID 911, version: 1060
[    6.245656] input: Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0/i2c_designware.4/i2c-4/i2c-GDIX1002:00/input/input7
[    6.258615] genirq: Failed to request resources for GDIX1002:00 (irq 130) on irqchip intel-gpio
[    6.259842] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: request IRQ failed: -5
[    6.465325] Goodix-TS: probe of i2c-GDIX1002:00 failed with error -5

root@Frenzy:~# uname -a
Linux Frenzy 6.2.0-32-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Aug 14 10:03:50 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@Frenzy:~# modinfo goodix_ts
filename:       /lib/modules/6.2.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen/goodix_ts.ko
license:        GPL v2
description:    Goodix touchscreen driver
author:         Bastien Nocera <hadess@hadess.net>
author:         Benjamin Tissoires <benjamin.tissoires@gmail.com>
srcversion:     B550E8B9ADBD69F9B7F7157
alias:          i2c:GDIX1001:00
alias:          acpi*:GDIX1002:*
alias:          acpi*:GDIX1001:*
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           goodix_ts
vermagic:       6.2.0-32-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        17:07:5C:D4:CA:8D:0F:C3:00:20:02:47:F9:D1:5A:9A:FF:5C:4B:F5
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      22:93:E1:C3:C5:61:81:63:5B:03:25:A5:F5:A0:C8:07:9A:C5:06:CC:
        53:41:1E:C0:45:23:22:58:A3:88:D0:E3:B4:D4:B0:FA:BD:FC:C2:4F:
        A8:A8:25:38:8C:7C:BB:85:27:63:06:4C:07:BB:AB:87:08:CD:6D:4A:
        53:C5:0A:5F:69:4D:41:A9:99:02:1C:2C:F8:57:9E:30:F5:16:33:AB:
        EF:D8:CE:E8:60:36:2D:44:10:5F:78:F0:24:F9:A5:D9:E8:38:96:DE:
        74:43:1A:83:DD:C3:24:2E:C7:2F:9F:AE:E7:90:B9:C8:91:2F:FB:40:
        7E:CC:93:B2:11:19:E4:78:86:4E:0A:0C:F4:21:1A:7C:E1:6D:52:A7:
        79:0C:25:41:81:FF:CA:79:82:D5:55:6C:6A:81:95:2F:52:E3:0D:7F:
        11:AF:26:10:CF:03:9B:5D:DE:72:EA:76:36:0B:6F:BC:94:24:C3:A4:
        95:ED:AF:42:A7:E3:44:B2:D9:C3:02:09:78:2C:71:B6:3F:A9:B2:0E:
        F2:16:45:E6:58:AB:A1:F2:5A:2F:C7:1E:86:B1:98:C2:B3:25:3B:DF:
        27:24:3A:94:55:4A:2B:C5:A2:D2:D6:5B:C7:D0:21:78:E2:8A:64:C9:
        E7:44:7F:E4:F3:00:A5:FA:09:E7:8A:BD:92:66:AD:F9:27:8A:F4:8B:
        6D:71:4E:88:BE:C1:F8:F2:40:5A:EE:91:C3:6C:5D:B3:ED:4C:06:47:
        54:0B:1B:27:2C:3A:6D:45:9B:70:B0:FB:7B:42:D0:19:4A:1A:F0:F3:
        A3:00:0E:B0:7E:F5:9F:01:D8:51:43:81:97:E4:B4:9A:E4:8D:86:C9:
        29:20:92:FA:EC:67:C7:50:4E:82:60:51:BB:00:20:CC:32:C9:69:2C:
        F4:42:F8:A1:9D:38:5C:0B:49:8D:6C:D7:26:13:B9:90:3B:14:73:55:
        35:56:D9:10:C2:D0:CE:00:9F:A7:2D:08:9C:A9:6E:B2:35:29:C7:60:
        96:ED:2F:E6:D1:CE:13:94:93:1F:4A:E6:1E:4F:22:27:19:BA:1B:D7:
        96:DA:F0:8A:D3:C7:FD:D8:E1:DF:B5:CD:25:1B:2E:94:CA:C1:0D:C8:
        CA:1C:65:CE:67:84:6E:43:02:1E:86:06:43:64:67:A5:04:B7:79:FA:
        23:C6:EC:BE:78:BD:35:3C:62:6F:EF:BB:45:C2:26:C4:C7:10:90:64:
        FD:25:64:2D:81:26:A9:2C:F5:6E:BA:2D:E3:69:DF:93:3B:67:E9:C5:
        2D:23:C1:68:B3:BE:A5:6A:02:D9:E3:47:51:7F:55:73:72:F9:C1:D1:
        60:6F:2A:FC:9D:91:C6:4C:4A:55:CA:47

root@Frenzy:~# cat /proc/interrupts
            CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
   0:         21          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    2-edge      timer
   1:          0         46          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    1-edge      i8042
   4:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    4-fasteoi   idma64.8
   5:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    5-fasteoi   idma64.9
   8:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    8-fasteoi   rtc0
   9:          0      49159          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    9-fasteoi   acpi
  14:          0          0          0        631  IR-IO-APIC   14-fasteoi   INT3453:00, INT3453:01, INT3453:03
  15:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   15-fasteoi   INT3453:02
  20:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   20-fasteoi   i801_smbus
  27:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   27-fasteoi   idma64.0, i2c_designware.0
  28:          0          0        432          0  IR-IO-APIC   28-fasteoi   idma64.1, i2c_designware.1
  29:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   29-fasteoi   idma64.2, i2c_designware.2
  30:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   30-fasteoi   idma64.3, i2c_designware.3
  31:          0        191          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   31-fasteoi   idma64.4, i2c_designware.4
  32:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   32-fasteoi   idma64.5, i2c_designware.5
  33:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   33-fasteoi   idma64.6, i2c_designware.6
  34:       4625          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   34-fasteoi   idma64.7, i2c_designware.7
  35:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   35-fasteoi   idma64.12, pxa2xx-spi.12
  36:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   36-fasteoi   idma64.13, pxa2xx-spi.13
  37:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   37-fasteoi   idma64.14, pxa2xx-spi.14
  39:         52          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   39-fasteoi   mmc0
  42:          0         52          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   42-fasteoi   mmc1
 120:          0          0          0          0  DMAR-MSI    0-edge      dmar0
 121:          0          0          0          0  DMAR-MSI    1-edge      dmar1
 122:          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-0000:00:13.0    0-edge      PCIe PME
 123:          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-0000:00:13.2    0-edge      PCIe PME
 124:          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-0000:00:13.3    0-edge      PCIe PME
 125:          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-0000:00:14.0    0-edge      PCIe PME
 126:          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-0000:00:14.1    0-edge      PCIe PME
 127:          0        758          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-0000:00:15.0    0-edge      xhci_hcd
 128:          0          0     121756          0  IR-PCI-MSI-0000:00:12.0    0-edge      ahci[0000:00:12.0]
 129:          0          0          0        631  intel-gpio    1  HTIX5288:00
 131:          0          0          0         68  IR-PCI-MSI-0000:00:0f.0    0-edge      mei_me
 132:        505          0          0     216042  IR-PCI-MSI-0000:02:00.0    0-edge      iwlwifi
 133:          0          0          0          0  intel-gpio   20  es8316
 134:          0      39378          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-0000:00:02.0    0-edge      i915
 135:          0          0        834          0  IR-PCI-MSI-0000:00:0e.0    0-edge      AudioDSP
 NMI:        302        300        300        299   Non-maskable interrupts
 LOC:    7584958    7360618    7150309    7350773   Local timer interrupts
 SPU:          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
 PMI:        302        300        300        299   Performance monitoring interrupts
 IWI:       1404      15620       1361       1226   IRQ work interrupts
 RTR:          0          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
 RES:      57521      49374      49942      49089   Rescheduling interrupts
 CAL:     620561     429300     321699     308772   Function call interrupts
 TLB:     238258     237364     237152     237993   TLB shootdowns
 TRM:          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
 THR:          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
 DFR:          0          0          0          0   Deferred Error APIC interrupts
 MCE:          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
 MCP:        148        149        149        149   Machine check polls
 ERR:          0
 MIS:          0
 PIN:          0          0          0          0   Posted-interrupt notification event
 NPI:          0          0          0          0   Nested posted-interrupt event
 PIW:          0          0          0          0   Posted-interrupt wakeup event
```

The problem seems like it can't allocate an interrupt for the touchscreen, but I could be interpreting that incorrectly.  Anyone have any ideas how I might go about correcting this issu